# Loading an Array with all your contact emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I need to load an array with all my contact emails to test to see if a new submitted email would be a duplicate.

I can load an array from a sheet range, a Drive folder, or  Docsapp elements.  But none of the classes and methods in ContactsApp seem to get the job done.... closest I got was .

var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts().valueOf(); but it returns me only the object "contact" for each contact.  I need an array filled with all the contact emails.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I use to get all my contacts for webapps.

```
function getAllContacts(){
  var contacts=ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var vA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    var l=contacts[i].getEmails().length;
    if(l){
      for(j=0;j<l;j++){
        vA.push([contacts[i].getEmails()[j].getAddress()]);
      }
    }
  }
  return vA;
}
```